# replace method in delegate string

Tags: c#, delegates, replace

i have got a little problem i received some data and show it in textbox to invoke it i used

```
if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
{
    // this is worker thread
    updatetextBoxDelegate del = new updatetextBoxDelegate(updatetextBox);
    textBox1.Invoke(del, new object[] { data });
}
```

my data is like 
name:sam
age:10

now i want to split it and save these values in array or show in sperate textboxes
i used replace method like

```
string str = textBox1.text;
str.Replace("name","");
```

and so on but the problem is replace method is not working on it it doses not replace any thing 
tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx, you'll see the `Replace` method returns a string you have to "catch" it, so replace:

```
str.replace("name","");
```

with

```
str = str.Replace("name", "");
```