# Replace a char with a string

Tags: c#, replace

How can I replace a char in a string with a string?

For Example:
Replace all char's 'e' with "test": "Hello World" -> "Htestllo World".

A, string.replace(char,string), if you will.

Comment: Any chance you could just treat the character as a string and use the `String.Replace(String, String)` one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550042/replace-method-in-delegate-string/

Comment: Observe that you want to replace a one character string "e" with a string. So build a mono-character temporary string.

Comment: Your question is "replace a char with a string", but your example shows "replacing all occurrences of a char with a different char". They're not the same thing at all. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I updated my example. I see why it appeared confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// let's pretend this was a char that came to us from somewhere, already as a char...
char c = char.Parse("e");

// Here is the string we want to change...
string str1 = "Hello World."

// now we'll have to convert the char we have, to a string to perform the replace...
string charStr = c.ToString();

// now we can do the replace...
string str2 = str1.Replace(charStr,"test");
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I ended up having to do something more complex as I was messing with UTF8/UTF16 stuff as I'm reading from a file. But this is what I was originally looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the string version of the Replace method:

```
"Hello World".Replace("e", "a long string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to replace any occurance of a string within a string, with another string.

> Returns a **new string** in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Example usage:

```
string original = "Hello world";
string changed = original.Replace("e", "t");
Console.WriteLine(changed); // "Htllo world"
```